# react-native expo deep linking -how to get a shareable link of my app

Tags: react-native, expo, share, deep-linking

Functional Requirement: As a user 1, I want to share the link of a my profile screen to anyone by whatsapp/sms/email so that when he clicks that link, he will navigate to my app's user profile screen.

In the app, my profile has a button "Share"
When I click "Share" button, I want the URL to be the link of the my profile screen.

Question:
**How to get the URL from deep linking and pass it in Share function?**

Technical requirement: From the documentation in expo and other similar question in stack overflow, my understanding is that I can achieve it by using deep linking functionality.
However I am still not clear how to do it.

Environment:
React native app using Expo

A.Content of App.js

A-1 Screen navigation: Search profile screen-->Search result screen-->Profiledetails screen

```
const Searchafterloginstack = createStackNavigator({
  SearchhomePostlogin: { screen: SearchhomePostlogin },
  SearchresultPostlogin: { screen: SearchresultPostlogin },
  Profiledetails: { screen: Profiledetails },
});
```

A-2. Bottom navigator

```
const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
           Login: {screen: Loginstack},
          });
```

A-3. Another Bottom navigator

```
const PostloginNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {screen: PostloginFeed},
  Find: {screen: Searchafterloginstack}
  });
```

A-4. Appcontainer

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  { Prelogin: AppNavigator,
    Postlogin: PostloginNavigator,
  },
  {initialRouteName: 'AppNavigator'}
));


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />
  }
};
```

=============================================
B. Profiledetails.js  (Profiledetails screen with "Share" button)
Screen navigation: Search profile screen-->Search result screen-->Profiledetails screen

```
export default class Profiledetails extends React.Component {
onShareMessage= ()=> {
          Share.share({
          url: Need help to get from deep linking-to navigate to profiledetails screen,
                   })
             }

render() {
        return (
<View >
<Text > {this.state.Name}  </Text>
<Button title="Share" onPress={this.onShareMessage}/>
</View>

)}
}
```

Comment: Do you have an endpoint to fetch the profile details with username or id or something?

Comment: Yes. Comes from state navigation